# Is it a good idea to add hidden competitor names on our website home page?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords

Is it a good idea to put the competitor names on our website home page (with the same color of the page background) to drive some traffic to our website?

Comment: For all SEO related question, ask yourself: Will this improve my website for my visitors? 99% of the time it has the same answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**'Hidden' black-on-black text will hurt your SEO rather than help it.**

Google can and does detect attempts to game their system, and may penalise or remove you from their index for it.

It is also very bad for accessibility, as visitors with screen readers will hear a list of your competitor names.

You could instead:

- Present a table of how your products differ from your competitors.
- Create landing pages, one for each competitor (titled “Alternative to x for y”, where x is your competitor name and y is what you do) to drive traffic to your site that way.

If your competitor names appear on your site, they should be legible and relevant to visitors reading the page. Attempting to stuff hidden keywords onto a page is not a good practice to follow.